# Can you explain this equation to someone who hasn't learned integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have just entered 11th grade and started limits on my own but my Physics textbook has an equation which I don't understand, I suspect it uses integration which I haven't learned yet. So can someone explain this equation to me:-

The question is:-

> **Find the value of $n$ (by using dimensional analysis):**
>   $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}} = a^n \sin^{-1} [\frac{x}{a} -1] $$

The equation looks similar to $$ v^2-u^2 = 2ax $$ But I don't understand what $dx$ means.

Comment: There's no way around learning what an integral means here. The left-hand side of the equation _is_ an integral, and so the exercise can't make sense to you until you know integrals.

Comment: You asked the same question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185710

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really an alternative to learning what an integral means here. The left-hand side of the equation *is* an integral, and so the exercise can't make sense to you until you know integrals.

The best we can do without writing an entire textbook here is:

**For the purpose of dimensional analysis** it is enough to know that an integral $\int f(x)\,dx$ is a limit of certain sums of terms of the form $f(x_1)\cdot(x_2-x_3)$. So your left-hand side
$$ \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}} $$
has the same dimension as
$$ \frac{x_2-x_3}{\sqrt{2ax_1-x_1^2}} $$
where of course all the $x_i$s have the same dimension as the $x$. This turns out to mean that the value of the integral is dimensionless.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try dimensional analysis the LHS is a sum of quantities that have $[x]-\sqrt{[x]^2}$ dimension i.e the integral is dimensionless.

The RHS should be dimensionless. The arcsine is dimensionless $a$ has the dimension of $[x]$ (in the denominator of the integral $ax$ is added to $x^2$) so $n=0$